# filter the new table by range of data, e.g. 1997-2020 PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Error:The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.
I intend to select Data by datecolumns from 1997 to 2020. But no success

```
New Periode = 
VAR DateStart =
    DATE ( "1997", "1", "1" )
VAR DateEnd =
    DATE ( "2021", "11", "10" )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        'Date_data',
        FILTER ( 'Date_data', 'Date_data'[Date] <= DateEnd && 'Date_data'[Date]  >= DateStart )
    )
```

Comment: What is 'Date_data'? table or column? can you add some sample date and your expected output from them?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this below code-

```
Periode = 

VAR DateStart = DATE ( "1997", "1", "1" )
VAR DateEnd = DATE ( "2021", "11", "10" )

RETURN
CALCULATETABLE (
    'Date_data',
    'Date_data'[Date] <= DateEnd 
        && 'Date_data'[Date]  >= DateStart
)
```